# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL

Tags: command-line, nvidia, compiling, libraries, opencl

Currently trying to compile a simple program given in OpenCL from [this](https://github.com/HandsOnOpenCL/Exercises-Solutions/tree/master/Exercises/Exercise01/Cpp) website. It will give me the required `DeviceInfo` that I need. After simply invoking a `make`, I get the error below:

```
sharan@sharan-X550CC:~/opencl-ex/Ex1$ make 
g++ DeviceInfo.cpp -I ../../Cpp_common  -lOpenCL -o DeviceInfo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'DeviceInfo' failed
make: *** [DeviceInfo] Error 1
```

Now I have installed using the instructions from [this](https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/) website. However, I still the get the error above.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You linker can't find the `OpenCL` library.

You should help the linker to find the `OpenCL` library.

Similar issue was raised [here](https://github.com/nginnever/zogminer/issues/54)

The solution there was to make a link for the library to a known lib location:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so
```

**Another option:**

Assuming that `OpenCL` library located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` you can also add the library folder to the Libraries path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
```

You may need to update the "Dynamic Linker":

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: This worked for me! The very first answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As already stated by Yaron the linker does not know where to find the OpenCL library, i.e. it is in none of the places it looks for it.

Instead of moving it to one of those places (e.g. `/usr/lib`) I would suggest to inform the linker where to look for it via the `-L` flag.
The command would then read (note the `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`)

```
g++ DeviceInfo.cpp -I ../../Cpp_common -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lOpenCL -o DeviceInfo
```

If you are using a handwritten `Makefile` you can simply modify the compiler/linker command like this. Otherwise you will have to touch your build system how to include it.

Comment: or try `LDFLAGS` e.g. `make 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'`

Comment: If your looking for a purely temporary solution this will also do the trick. However I advise to make it `LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to preserve any previous settings